# Suggestions on how to consistently get more outputs?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, rpc, monerod-commands, transaction-unlock-time

I've got a service that frequently runs out of outputs. For this service, sending a heavily split transaction back to my wallet is not practical. Ideally, I would want something like the my return output to be split up multiple times.

What are some other options I can use to get more outputs in my wallet?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at a [response](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/2351#issuecomment-325111072) to issue [#2351](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/2351):

> You can send 50 monero 20 times in one tx to yourself (make sure you have set merge-destinations to 0 first). This will break up the 1000 output.
>   Also set min-outputs-count and min-outputs-value to, say, 20 and 10, see the commit message for [0ad87db](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/0ad87db01f19eff22ab9c3998826b7aa943975cf) for an explantion of how they work. Last, you can pay several destinations in the same tx, which means no intervening change. Payment id is per tx, so if you have two payment ids, you have to make two txes at least. Just make the payout limit higher for people with a payment id.

Maybe that's what you are looking for.